# comparing data in lists Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

how to compare more then one list, below works ok for just 2 lists but what if more needed

```
while (list1[0:1] == list2[0:1]):
    if list1[1:2] > list2[1:2]:
        print('list 1 wins')
    elif list1[2:3] > list2[2:3]:
        print('list 1 wins!')
    elif list1[3:4] > list2[3:4]:
        print('list 1 wins')
    elif list1[4:5] > list2[4:5]:
        print('list 1 wins')
    elif list1[5:5] == list2[5:5]:
        print('its a tie')
    else:
        print('list 2 wins')
    break
```

Comment: why use `while` ? in this case `while` works like `if` because of `break`

Comment: Lowest or highest, you use both in your description. Currently it is testing for highest.

Comment: Do you actually need to associate a unique string to each separate list - (so that it can be printed in like your example?

Comment: ```sum(candidate1) -> 48```

Comment: Are you always comparing just two *totals*?  or could you compare totals from say five candidates? or *n* candidates?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out lists can be directly compared without iterating through them.
But when you want to work with multiple lists at the same time it is idiomatic to use `zip()`, e.g.:

```
for i1, i2 in zip(list1, list2):
    if i1 > i2:
        print("List 1 wins")
        break
    if i2 > i1:
        print("List 2 wins")
        break
else:
    print("It's a tie")
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists and tuples can be compared just like that assuming that the matching elements are comparable:

```
>>> list1=[50,9,5,4,5]
>>> list2=[50,9,8,1,5]
>>> list1 > list2
False
>>> list1 < list2
True
```

That also means that you can order any number of lists:

```
>>> lists = [list1, list2, list3]
>>> lists.sort()
```

Comment: ```sorted(lists)``` or ```lists.sort()``` ...?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using a for-loop?

The syntax is:

```
for value in list:
    # do something
    print value
```

and then there is the ([zip function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip))

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [a,b]
zip(list1, list2) # = [(1,a),(2,b)]
```

With these two tools one is able to provide a really pythonic solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As bereal says, you can just use list comparison for this. If ties weren't an issue, you could just use `max()` to determine a winner, but to handle ties you need to sort the whole collection of lists.

Eg, this code will handle any number of lists.

```
list1 = [50,9,5,4,5]
list2 = [50,9,8,1,6]
list3 = [50,9,8,1,5]

lists = [(seq, i) for i, seq in enumerate((list1, list2, list3), 1)]
lists.sort(reverse=True)

if lists[0][0] == lists[1][0]:
    print("it's a tie")
else:
    print("list {0} wins: {1}".format(lists[0][1], lists[0][0]))
```

**output**

```
list 2 wins: [50, 9, 8, 1, 6]
```

If you change `list2` back to `[50, 9, 8, 1, 6]`, then `it's a tie` will get printed.

`lists` is a list of tuples, with each tuple containing one of the original lists and its index number, so we can identify lists after the tuples have been sorted. The sorting will compare the lists, and if two lists are identical, then the indices will also be compared, but that doesn't affect the desired outcome here.

BTW, `list1[1:2] > list2[1:2]` is wasteful. It creates a new pair of single element lists & compares them. It's easier to just compare the elements themselves, eg `list1[1] > list2[1]`.